# Moving method after JButton selection

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

When I select the first option and hit select the JFrame stays as is and I want it to close and move into the next method being called and open a different JFrame. Can anyone see the problem? I can't figure out where I am going wrong

```
public class GUI extends JFrame 
    {
    public static void main(String args [])
    {       
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Choose an option");
    frame.setSize(350, 180);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(
      JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));

    final JRadioButton sb = new JRadioButton("Student");
    final JRadioButton lb = new JRadioButton("Lecturer");
    final JRadioButton cdb = new JRadioButton("Course Director");
    final JRadioButton ab = new JRadioButton("Admin");
    ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup.add(sb);
    buttonGroup.add(lb);
    buttonGroup.add(cdb);
    buttonGroup.add(ab);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(sb);
    panel.add(lb);
    panel.add(cdb);
    panel.add(ab);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
    JButton select = new JButton("Select");
    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(sb.isSelected())
            {
                frame.dispose();
                StudentGUI();
            }
            else if(lb.isSelected())
                System.out.println("Lecturer");
            else if(cdb.isSelected())
                System.out.println("Course Director");
            else if(ab.isSelected())
                System.out.println("Admin");
        }
    });
    cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.add(select);
    panel2.add(cancel);
    panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 0));
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }

 public static void StudentGUI() 
 {
    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Input Username");
    frame1.setSize(350, 180);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(
      JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextField tf = new JTextField("Input username here");
    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.add(tf);
    panel1.add(submit);
    frame1.getContentPane().add(panel1);
}
```

Comment: What does your code currently do?

Comment: It creates a JFrame with 4 JRadioButtons and 2 JButtons, a select button and a cancel button. The cancel button kills the program. I want to next open up another JFrame to anothe menu. When I run it it opens up grand but it won't move on when I select the option

Comment: Consider posting more code. Not all of your code, but just enough to compile, run and show your problem. Note as an aside, it's usually not a great idea to use swapping JFrame's as a basis for your user interface as most users don't like this.

Comment: Following on from what @HovercraftFullOfEels said, consider using a cardlayout

Comment: Ok I'll post more code. Thanks for the advice, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set `frame1.setVisible(true);` in your `StudentGUI` method, and you never close the window in the first method (use `yourframe.dispose()`).

So try:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(sb.isSelected())
                StudentGUI();
            else if(lb.isSelected())
                System.out.println("Lecturer");
            else if(cdb.isSelected())
                System.out.println("Course Director");
            else if(ab.isSelected())
                System.out.println("Admin");
            yourframe.dispose();//don't know your frame variable
        }



public static void StudentGUI() 
 {
    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Input Username");
    frame1.setSize(350, 180);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(
      JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
     //code omitted
}
```

Comment: Got it, was just a silly mistake, just needed a fresh set of eyes. Thanks

Comment: @user3025755 We all do it sometimes, don't worry :)